# Unable to send email with multiple cc in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("ID");
  var ccID = ss.getRange("A2").getValue`enter code here`(); 
  var id = 'Mis@labotek.in';
  var subject = "Testing mail automation";
  var text = "Response Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AbqJfsJxkJ57vADbcAYDKrR3Sj5JJlzjm2Ve6xqtUWA/edit#gid=1748528068"
  GmailApp.sendEmail(id,subject,text,{
    cc : ccID;
  })
}
```

[Note: value of ccID is 'cankc1990@gmail.com,kknitish1990@gmail.com,nihilnitin@gmail.com' which i fetched from the sheet from cell A2 only.

and this is the error shown
Error Message
Execution log
11:28:53 PM Notice  Execution started
11:28:52 PM Info    'cankc1990@gmail.com,kknitish1990@gmail.com,nihilnitin@gmail.com'
11:28:54 PM Error
Exception: Invalid argument: : Invalid Cc header
myFunction  @ Code.gs:17

Thanks in advance]

Comment: Remove the semicolon. `GmailApp.sendEmail(id,subject,text,{ cc : ccID })`

Comment: Still didt work

Answer (score 0):

Use: sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)
[cc String  a comma-separated list of email addresses to CC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))